# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined is thrown while accessing this field

**alert(event.target.value)**

```
import React , { useState }from 'react';
import {DashboardLayout} from '../components/Layout';
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
    { value: 'ami-abc*', label: 'ami-abc' },
    { value: 'ami-xyz*', label: 'ami-xyz' },
]

const DiscoverAMIPage = () => {
    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
            <h2>Discovered AMI</h2>
            <Select
                onChange={handleChange}
                options={options}
            />
        </DashboardLayout>
    )
}

function handleChange(event) {
    alert(event.target.value)
}
export default DiscoverAMIPage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onChange` in `react-select` return `value` not an `event`: https://react-select.com/props

```
function handleChange(value) {
  alert(value)
}
```